# Stock balance from items in Boms

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Bom table like

```
ItemCode  MatCode  Quantity 
 032490   M10506     3.0 
 032490   M10507     1.0
 032490   M10509     1.0
 030515   M10506     2.0
 030515   M10508     5.0
 045660   M10507     2.0
 045660   M10510     3.0
```

Stock balance is known for assembled items in Item table.

```
 ItemCode   StockBalance
  032490        10
  030515        15
  045660         8
  M10506     
  M10507     
  M10508     
  M10509     
  M10510
```

I need to calculate balance for all materials (MatCode) in Stock as part of assembled products. So in my example for M10506 it would be 10*3+15*2.

I'm stuck with this, looping the query and right now there's only 1 level boms but in future there will be 2 and 3 level boms.

My query:

```
Select sum(item.StockBalance * bom.Quantity) from item 
 inner join bom on bom.ItemCode=item.itemcode
 Where  exists (select * from bom WHERE Item.itemCode = bom.ItemCode)
 Group by bom.ItemCode
```

Comment: Can you add your script with the question we are here to help you with your code not write it for you :)

Comment: Will you please also explain what 'Boms' is? Please don't assume that your target audience knows the nuances of your work.

Comment: Sorry, BOM=Bill Of Materials

Comment: One other thing, I just noticed that 'ItemCode' appears to include 'MatCode'. Is this correct? If yes, why are they mixed together?

Comment: Item table has all items, including material items and assembled items, packaking materials etc.

Comment: So can a material have a Stockbalance in Item?  Or will it always be NULL?  Or if it could have a value, would that matter in the calculation?

Comment: @LukStorms  For Material items it is always NULL. Stock balance in item table is finished goods' stockbalance

Comment: In that case, Gordon Linoff's answer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data suggests a `join` and aggregation:

```
select b.matCode, sum(b.quantity * i.StockBalance)
from bom b join
     item i
     on b.itemCode = i.itemCode
group by b.matCode;
```

Comment: I am not sure if group by matCode will be enough. Maybe you also need to group on ItemCode ?

Comment: This helped, thanks. Group by matcode is enough. When grouping also with itemcode result is not correct.